# Can we able to test static boardcast receivers in Instrumetation tests or boardcast receivers should be tested in unit test only

Tags: android, unit-testing, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, instrumented-test

I am new to Android and its Instrumentation testing

I am having a boardcast receiver registered in my android manifest like

```
<receiver android:name=".phone.PhoneCallReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and PhoneCallReceiver class is like below

```
    public class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
                
             if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) {
             String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            showAddCallLogScreen();
        }
            });
           
         }
       
     }`
```

I want to test whether Add call log pop up page displayed in the instrumentation test when call is ended , I tried to mock the call ended using below intent

My instrumentation test is like

```
    @Test
    public void testSystemCallLog(){
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
        intent(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER, wotkNumber);
        intent(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE, "IDLE");

       LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

I tried with this too
InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getContext().sendBroadcast(intent); too

But it also didn't work

Any idea how to mock a call in instrumentation test or how to test boardcast receivers in instrumentation test ?

or boardcast receivers can tested only in unit cases ?